# PowerShell Cannot dot-source this command because it was defined in a different language mode

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell

I've created a Windows application package using Visual Studio and when I run Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 script I get this error on some computers.

> Cannot dot-source this command because it was defined in a different language mode. To invoke this command without importing its contents omit the '.' operator`

I feel like this has something to do with the Group Policy since the particular device is an Enterprise issued Microsoft Surface 2. I cannot make any changes to this group policy.

How do I proceed to install this application on this device?

Anything in particular I should try?

[image: Picture of error provided by employee running in to the issue]

Comment: If you think the issue is with group policy (and that is definitely possible) then you need to talk to your Admins and get them to either install it for you or make an exception to the policy for your machine.

Comment: @EBGreen, Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure if it's group policy or not. It seems like my research on the issue is pointing to that though. It's working on some devices which is weird for a group policy related issue.

Comment: You could try doing a RSOP on your machine although if you are not an admin you probably won't be able to get machine level results. Personally I would suggest contacting your Admins. They should be able to track it down if it is policy related.

Comment: You are already at a PowerShell prompt, so you don't need `PowerShell -noexit -file`. Just type the filename of the script directly at the PowerShell prompt and press Enter.

Comment: I will try this, thank you.

Comment: I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unrestricted execution policy?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Restrict it after you're done. It is a loophole if your admins didn't plug it.

Comment: Try just running the script without the powershell -noexit - file. I am with bill from the comments. You would need all that if you were using cmd..

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Both bypass and unrestricted have had no effect on this.
BTW, I am trying to "dot source" my $Profile which is on a SHARE.
Even copying it to the local drive had no effect.
Next to investigate if there is some type of alternate stream (remove) but that should have been covered by setting the execution policy

Comment: There are no alternate streams on my file ($Profile)